# How can I know what are the value I have posted in php?

Tags: php, html

In my list there are some name of the input box, it follow the order of 1 2 3....,

```
<input type= "text" name="text1">
<input type= "text" name="text2">
<input type= "text" name="text3">
```

that means the post name = text 1 text 2 text 3

However, since the number is not fixed, i don't how many textbox is actually there,  how can i **get all the name** after i posted the form?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text[]` as the name of all your input elements instead of `text1`, `text2` etc. You can then get the values as `$_POST['text']`, which will be an array. This array will contain as many values as your form contained text boxes.

**Update:** if you cannot change the HTML (which is unfortunate) you can get the names of the submitted variables by doing this:

```
$names = array_filter(array_keys($_POST),
                      function ($k) { return substr($k, 0, 4) == 'text'; });
```

Comment: Are there any other ways? because i can not change the name to an array for some reason

Comment: Sorry how can i call this function?

Comment: @LeoChan: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, i mean if the input name is Name100 , Name1 , Name2 ,Name101,Name103, can i use this code do it?

Comment: @LeoChan: Use it and see what happens. I don't see why you have to ask.

Comment: I use this to check 
foreach ($names as $set)
{echo $set;}

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name = $value";
}
```

should give you the idea

or you can use array text[]:

```
<input type= "text" name="text[]">
<input type= "text" name="text[]">
<input type= "text" name="text[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a hidden field whose value is the names of all such fields.

```
PUT THIS IN THE HTML FORM
<input type= "text" name="text1" value="1" />
<input type= "text" name="text2" value="2" />
<input type= "text" name="text3" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="textContainer" value="text1,text2,text3" />
```

Then, you can get this variable in PHP like this:

```
<?php
    $textFields = trim( $_POST[ 'textContainer' ] );
    $textFields = explode( ',', $textFields );

    $fields = array(); // this array will contain all text fields with names text1, text2 as keys
    foreach( $textFields as $key => $value ) {
         $fields[ $value ] = $_POST[ $value ];
    }

    /* $fields is now an array like below:
    Array (
      'text1' => 1,
      'text2' => 2,
      'text3' => 3
    )*/
?>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: @leo-chan - let me know if this works. You can set the hidden field value to all the field names that you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the `$_POST` array itself

Just do a `foreach loop` however, keep in mind, it is best to **know** what values are being passed, by doing a *catch all* maneuver like this, you open yourself up to possible injection and attack.